# Nginx does not forwards remote address to gunicorn

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have the following nginx configuration to forward requests to gunicorn.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

However, when I access remote address using `request.META['REMOTE_ADDR']`, it always returns `127.0.0.1`. I am using Django 1.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct and expected behavior. If you would like to access users IP you will need to use:

```
request.META['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']
```

Note that in development (without running nginx), `REMOTE_ADDR` is still correct.

My recommendation is to add a middleware or a utility method which will do the conditional logic to get the actual users IP depending on your settings.